# Index range borders

Tags: python, while-loop

I am making a task where I need to pack the same symbols into sublists. My code works, but the last symbol is ignored. Obviousely, I need to set the borders for index to include the last one (the length is 11 in my test variable, so, the last one should be 10). But when I include this for i or j (replace < with <=) my loop goes out of range... I do not understand, why this happens. Could someone explain?

Yes, I can add an if loop to include the last value into the correct position, but its sort of cheating.

```
test = 'abccdeeefgg'
ml = []
i = 0

while i < len(test) - 1:
    print(i)
    elem = []
    elem.append(test[i])
    j = i + 1
    while test[i] == test[j] and j < len(test) - 1:
        print(i, j)
        elem.append(test[j])
        i = j
        j += 1
    ml.append(elem)
    i += 1

print(ml)
```

The output is:
0
1
2
(2 3)
4
5
(5 6)
(6 7)
8
9

[['a'], ['b'], ['c', 'c'], ['d'], ['e', 'e', 'e'], ['f'], ['g']]

I have put the i and j values into brackets - those are values that are given by the inner while loop.
I have inserted print command for i and i and j indeces to follow the process.

Comment: note that when you do `j = i+1` and later  do `i =j` .. you have essentially incremented the loop variable at that point

Answer (score 0):

Your loop is going out of range in the case where `j = len(test)`
. This case is possible, because the last instruction of your loop is `j += 1`, and then you try accessing the value with `test[j]` before checking if the access is valid.
Change the condition order with `j < len(test) and test[i] == test[j]` first to be sure j is valid, then using it as an index.

Comment: Wow! Thanks! Never thought their order is so important, I thought they are evaluated at once.... Yes, that has solved the issue.